# How to retrieve MySQL table rows using versioning with pagination

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a reservation system which begun by storing a single reservation per row in a single table.  Here is a simplified outline of the schema:

```
reservation_id unsigned int auto_increment,
status enum('pending', 'accepted', 'cancelled', 'rejected')
check_in datetime,
check_out datetime
```

In the admin control panel the reservations can be viewed page by page- all is well.  However, the client then wanted to have revision requests for each reservation (i.e. their customers could request a change to their reservation dates which would be approved or not.  If not, then their original reservation would still hold).

The schema changed to this:

```
reservation_id unsigned int auto_increment,
revision unsigned int,
status enum('pending', 'accepted', 'cancelled', 'rejected', 'replaced')
check_in datetime,
check_out datetime
```

Now, since there are 1 or more rows per reservation the admin control panel has issues. The database pagination pulls 10 rows at a time, but there is no guarantee that all of the revisions of a particular reservation are gathered in the 'next' page.

To picture this with data, imagine the pagination pulls 3 rows per 'next' page:

```
reservation_id, revision
(1000, 1, 'accepted')
(1001, 1, 'replaced')
(1001, 2, 'replaced')
(1001, 3, 'accepted')   <--- this one is cut from the result set
...                          since it spans a page boundary
```

Since the original code assumed each row represented one reservation this is no longer going to work.

What is the best way to solve this problem please?  Is there a mysql query that will retrieve the next N reservations + revisions.  That is a variable number of rows depending on how many revisions are on each reservation.

Comment: And that's why you use the History Table pattern kids

Comment: You cannot enforce "3" rows per page, unless you paginate within `reservation_id`.  (There could be dozens of changes to a single reservation, correct?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I doubt that your reservation_id is still auto increment in the second example, since it has multiple rows with the same reservation_id.

Anyway, you can solve this with a subquery, like this:

```
select * from reservation R1
    join (select distinct reservation_id 
        from reservation order by reservation_id limit 0,3) R2 
            on R1.reservation_id=R2.reservation_id
```

First I wanted to use IN instead of a join, but my MySQL does not yet support LIMIT in IN/ALL/ANY/SOME type subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, your `revision` column it's just an incrementing number, isn't it? How do you link a reservation to its revisions?

First of all, I would add the `parent_id` column (integer, nullable) that should be filled with the linked reservation, creating a one-to-many relationship; all the revisions for a specific reservation should have its ID inside that field.

Then I would execute two different queries, one to get all the reservations (ie, all the rows with a `null` inside the `parent_id` column) and one to get all the revisions; I would apply the pagination to the reservations only, because they are your main entity (a reservation is a sub-entity as it can not exists without a reservation).